# libfuse: exiting fuse_session_loop

Tags: fuse

Context: Ubuntu 11.10 and libfuse 2.8.4-1.4ubuntu1
Linux 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I'm trying to use libfuse.  I want to cause fuse_session_loop to exit (from a signal handler or a different thread), but when I call fuse_session_exit nothing happens until the session receives a new request.

fuse_session_exit sets a flag that is read by fuse_session_exited.  Debugging into fuse_session_loop it appears to block on fuse_chan_recv, so it doesn't check fuse_session_exited again until the top of the loop...

```
int fuse_session_loop(struct fuse_session *se)
{
    int res = 0;
    struct fuse_chan *ch = fuse_session_next_chan(se, NULL);
    size_t bufsize = fuse_chan_bufsize(ch);
    char *buf = (char *) malloc(bufsize);
    if (!buf) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fuse: failed to allocate read buffer\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (!fuse_session_exited(se)) {
        struct fuse_chan *tmpch = ch;
        res = fuse_chan_recv(&tmpch, buf, bufsize); <--- BLOCKING
        if (res == -EINTR)
            continue;
        if (res <= 0)
            break;
        fuse_session_process(se, buf, res, tmpch);
    }

    free(buf);
    fuse_session_reset(se);
    return res < 0 ? -1 : 0;
}
```

fuse_chan_recv calls fuse_kern_chan_receive which blocks on the "read" syscall of the "/dev/fuse" device, so even though the fuse_session_exited flag is set nothing happens yet.

```
static int fuse_kern_chan_receive(struct fuse_chan **chp, char *buf,
                  size_t size)
{
    struct fuse_chan *ch = *chp;
    int err;
    ssize_t res;
    struct fuse_session *se = fuse_chan_session(ch);
    assert(se != NULL);

restart:
    res = read(fuse_chan_fd(ch), buf, size); <--- BLOCKING
    err = errno;

    if (fuse_session_exited(se))
        return 0;
    if (res == -1) {
        /* ENOENT means the operation was interrupted, it's safe
           to restart */
        if (err == ENOENT)
            goto restart;

        if (err == ENODEV) {
            fuse_session_exit(se);
            return 0;
        }
        /* Errors occuring during normal operation: EINTR (read
           interrupted), EAGAIN (nonblocking I/O), ENODEV (filesystem
           umounted) */
        if (err != EINTR && err != EAGAIN)
            perror("fuse: reading device");
        return -err;
    }
    if ((size_t) res < sizeof(struct fuse_in_header)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "short read on fuse device\n");
        return -EIO;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This problem seems to effect the hello_ll.c example provided with libfuse as well as my program.  It makes me think that perhaps there is some mechanism that is not working that should.  Perhaps fuse_session_exit is supposed to be also doing something that interrupts the read call, that for some reason is not working on my system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if a signal handler is executed while a system call (such as **read(2)**) is blocking, the system call returns immediately (after the signal handler is completed executing) with an **EINTR**.  This is clearly the behaviour that **fuse_session_loop** and **fuse_session_exit** were designed for.

However if the signal handler is installed with the **SA_RESTART** flag set (see **sigaction(2)**) the system call will not return with **EINTR** after the signal handler has executed.  The system call will resume blocking instead.

For some reason on my system (Ubuntu 11.10 x86_64) the default behaviour of **signal(2)** is to install the signal handler with the **SA_RESTART** flag.

ie the strace of the following program...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void f(int signum) {}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT,f);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

...is as follows...

```
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x400524, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f4997e1f420}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
```

For this reason the signals (in the examples provided with fuse and my own program) did not interrupt the blocking read in **fuse_kern_chan_receive** as their authors expected them too.

The fix was to use **sigaction(2)** (and leave **SA_RESTART** bit zeroed) to install the handler (instead of **signal(2)**).

An open question that still remains is why does a call to **signal(2)** have the **SA_RESTART** flag on by default?  I would expect interrupting (not restarting) is the expected default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This might be worth a bug report; it might also be closed as "working as expected".

That said, if you *also* send a signal to interrupt the `read()` call executing in the `fuse_kern_chan_receive()` function, it appears prepared to propagate the error up through the stack, which will trigger the `continue` in the higher-level call, which will notice the `exited` flag, and hopefully terminate the loop as cleanly as possible.

Try adding a `pthread_kill(3)` to kill the specific thread in question. `fuse_signals.c` installs handlers for `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` that call `fuse_session_exit()`.

Comment: I think Ive figured it out, I'm installing the signal handler with just a regular signal call which for some reason is getting passed to the kernel as: rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x40af90, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fcac93ea420}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0.  This has the SA_RESTART flag set for some reason so when the signal handler is called, the read syscall is not interrupted but resumed.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't solve the porblem by zeroing **SA_RESTART** flag for fuse 2.9.2.

Instead, I used a fake read when I want to exit.

1. Open the file before calling `fuse_session_exit`
2. Call `fuse_session_exit`
3. Read a byte from the file

Answer (score 0):

Read the manpage on signal: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html

> The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also
> varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its
> use: use sigaction(2) instead.  See Portability below.
>
> The only portable use of signal() is to set a signal's disposition
> to SIG_DFL or SIG_IGN.  The semantics when using signal() to
> establish a signal handler vary across systems (and POSIX.1
> explicitly permits this variation); do not use it for this purpose.
>
> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> - The kernel's signal() system call provides System V semantics.
> - By default, in glibc 2 and later, the signal() wrapper function
>   does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls
>   sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics.  This default
>   behavior is provided as long as the _BSD_SOURCE feature test macro
>   is defined.  By default, _BSD_SOURCE is defined; it is also
>   implicitly defined if one defines _GNU_SOURCE, and can of course
>   be explicitly defined.
> - On glibc 2 and later, if the _BSD_SOURCE feature test macro is not
>   defined, then signal() provides System V semantics.  (The default
>   implicit definition of _BSD_SOURCE is not provided if one invokes
>   gcc(1) in one of its standard modes (-std=xxx or -ansi) or defines
>   various other feature test macros such as _POSIX_SOURCE,
>   _XOPEN_SOURCE, or _SVID_SOURCE; see feature_test_macros(7).)

So GLibc used to have signal not restart afterwards but they changed
it to make it more compatible with BSD.